# Splash screen with version In MAUI

Tags: splash-screen, maui

I am trying to make a splash screen in .Net MAUI that contains app version. I have looked for many examples but none of them shows how to customize splash screen with version or text. Is it possible in .Net MAUI. If there is an example or a way to add app verion with logo in .Net MAUI please let me know.

Comment: Just create a ContentPage that acts as a Splash screen and add a timer that calls the next page...

Comment: OK Thanks I will try this ....Is this the only way ?

Comment: If you really need a custom Splash Screen, or rather a loading Page if you're loading some content in the background, then your only viable option is what FreakyAli wrote. That's an easy solution. The actual Splash Screen is a tricky thing, because you'll have to deal with platform specific differences. E.g., since Android 12, the possibilities are very limited: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen. For iOS, you'll need a storyboard: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/specifying-your-apps-launch-screen/ MAUI really just offers a common denominator

Comment: ok Thank you...Is there any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you can create a `ContentPage` that acts as a Splash screen ,just as FreakyAli said.

There is a sample code, you can refer to it.

**MySplashScreen.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamSample.MySplashScreen"
                          BackgroundColor="#000">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="10">
        <Image Source="test.png" x:Name="imgLogo" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"
               Margin="5"/>
        <Label Text="WHATSAPP" FontSize="Large" TextColor="#f7f7f7" Margin="5"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MySplashScreen.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class MySplashScreen : ContentPage 
      {
            public MySplashScreen ()
            {
                  InitializeComponent ();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
            LogoAnimation();
        }

        public async Task LogoAnimation()
        {
            imgLogo.Opacity = 0;
            await imgLogo.FadeTo(1, 3000);
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
    }
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new DarkScreen();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1.Here, I used `FadeTo` function to simulate the time delay. Of course, you can also use a `Timer` to acheve this.

2.You can add a `Label` to display the version name to page `MySplashScreen`  as needed.

Comment: I wanted to ask. In the App() constructor, when you write new DarkScreen() do you mean MySplashScreen() instead or the are a DarkScreen? Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a countdown timer to control the display time of your splash screen or loading page.

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new LoadingPage();
    }
}
```

and the LoadingPage.cs

```
public partial class LoadingPage : ContentPage
{
    private TimeSpan _countdownTimeout => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);   //n secs
    private IDispatcherTimer _countdownTimer { get; set; }

    public LoadingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //***redirect to appshell countdown timer initialize
        this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            _countdownTimer = LoadingLayout.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
            _countdownTimer.Interval = _countdownTimeout;
            _countdownTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                _countdownTimer.Stop();
                Application.Current.MainPage = new MainShell();  //redirect to main shell or page
            };
            _countdownTimer.Start();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**